# Different output while commenting out part of seperate declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've this chunk of code and I've stumbled upon something I don't understand.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

    void getMinMax(double &a, double& b, double& c, double*& ptrMin, double*& ptrMax) {

            if (a > b)
                swap(a, b);
            if (a > c)
                swap(a, c);
            if (b > c)
                swap(b, c);

            ptrMin = &a;
            ptrMax = &c;
    }


    void getMinMax(double *a, double* b, double* c, double** ptrMin, double** ptrMax) {

        if (*a > *b)
            swap(*a, *b);
        if (*a > *c)
            swap(*a, *c);
        if (*b > *c)
            swap(*b, *c);

        ptrMin = &a;
        ptrMax = &c;

    }

    void ord3(double& a, double& b, double& c) {

        if (a > b)
            swap(a, b);
        if (a > c)
            swap(a, c);
        if (b > c)
            swap(b, c);
    }

    void ord3(double* a, double* b, double* c) {

        if (*a > *b)
            swap(*a, *b);
        if (*a > *c)
            swap(*a, *c);
        if (*b > *c)
            swap(*b, *c);
    }

    void printOrd(const double* a, const double* b, const double* c) {
        cout << *a << " " << *b << " " << *c << endl;
    }

    void printMinMax(const double* pmn, const double* pmx) {
        cout << "Min = " << *pmn << "; "
        << "Max = " << *pmx << endl;
    }


    int main() {

        double a, b, c, *ptrMin, *ptrMax;

        a = 2; b = 1; c = 3;
        ord3(a,b,c);
        printOrd(&a, &b, &c);

        a = 3; b = 2; c = 1;
        ord3(&a,&b,&c);
        printOrd(&a, &b, &c);

        a = -1; b = -1; c = 1;
        ord3(&a,&b,&c);
        printOrd(&a, &b, &c);


        /*a = 2; b = 3; c = 1;
        getMinMax(a,b,c,ptrMin,ptrMax);
        printMinMax(ptrMin, ptrMax);*/

        a = 3; b = 1; c = 2;
        getMinMax(&a,&b,&c,&ptrMin,&ptrMax);
        printMinMax(ptrMin, ptrMax);


        a = 3; b = 3; c = -1;
        getMinMax(&a,&b,&c,&ptrMin,&ptrMax);
        printMinMax(ptrMin, ptrMax);

}
```

I've discovered that when I'm commenting out this part:

```cpp
*a = 2; b = 3; c = 1;
getMinMax(a,b,c,ptrMin,ptrMax);
printMinMax(ptrMin, ptrMax);
```

then I get an output like this:

[image: buggy output showing garbage values for float values]

but when I run this normally, I get what I was expecting:

[image: normal output with expected results]

How is this possible?
In my view, this is totally separate declaration and shouldn't affect rest of the code or am I missing something?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can have effects at a distance, and even backwards in time.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites for things relevant to the question. *Especially* don't link to images. Please post everything relevant *in* the question, as *text*.

Comment: Why don't you just use [std::minmax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax), [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) or one of the other readily available algorithms to get the minimum or maximum from a container? This, to me, looks like a bunch of redundant code that should be replaced with one or two lines utilizing a standard algorithm.

Comment: Why exactly are you treating a non-pointer variable as a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `getMinMax` where you pass values by pointer, the assignments at the end change the *local* variables, not the values pointed to.  You need to remove a level of indirection to get to the values from the caller:

```
*ptrMin = a;
*ptrMax = c;
```

This worked with the reference version enabled because it was updating the variables in `main` (although the subsequent result may not have been the correct min/max values).

Comment: "You need to remove a level of indirection .." - No, he needs to stop reinventing the wheel and start using [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).